# absolutely centering a table in a Latex document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, center

I am trying to center a table in Latex and it is in a book.

```
\begin{table}[b!]
\centering      
\tabcolsep=3.0pt
\begin{tabular}{r|rrr|rrrr|rrrr}
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{temp123445} &        \multicolumn{4}{c}{abcdefrw} &               \multicolumn{4}{c}{bnopfsdtagfweau} \\
$\alpha$ & \# ter & \% gap &         refw & \# ter & \% gap &    rewf & \# path & \# ter & \% gap &  esd  & \# gred \\
\hline     
    1.60 &     56 &   2.93 &      1191.34 &     34 &   0.05 &  546.43 &    1300 &     31 &   0.38 & 401.20 &   1116 \\
    2.43 &      3 &   8.45 &      1680.47 &     21 &   1.45 &  410.74 &    6428 &     16 &   2.65 & 816.47 &   5896 \\
    2.75 &      9 &   3.97 &       903.57 &     19 &   1.71 &  480.65 & 169,286 &     56 &   2.15 & 539.52 & 11,209 \\
    2.30 &     54 &   2.40 &       798.33 &     56 &   1.97 &  449.87 & 855,441 &     21 &   1.55 & 830.85 & 10,110 \\
    2.50 &     22 &   0.91 &       654.06 &      9 &     -- &  957.18 &      -- &     26 &   0.80 & 475.83 &   7743 \\
    3.75 &     23 &   0.70 &       554.46 &      5 &     -- &  998.54 &      -- &     27 &   0.68 & 577.48 &   7479 \\
    6.00 &     43 &   0.61 &       470.26 &      3 &     -- & 1627.80 &      -- &     28 &   0.58 & 628.28 &   7048 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results on bad data.}\label{tab:results-bad}
\end{table}
```

I think this is centering only based on the margins. Can I ignore the margins and center it in the page of a book?

[image]

Comment: as always on this site, please always provide a full but minimal example not these un compilable sniplets. Provide something that can be copied and tested as is.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `chngpage` package and its `adjustwidth` env

Comment: Which font and which font size do you employ? How wide is the textblock?

Comment: Sorry! It's part of a rather huge document. I am trying to compose a MWE.

Comment: this is the template I am using https://github.com/fwalch/tum-thesis-latex

Comment: If your document has different layout on odd and even pages then by default the answer is no, although you could use a two pass system to check whether the float was on an odd or even page (using \pageref` essentially) and adjust the position accordingly.

Comment: A table is part of the text and traditionally is located with respect to the text. If you want your table be centered with respect to the page width then the text should also be centered with respect to the page width (i.e. equal margins). It is OK, but inadvisable, to have an overwide table centered wrt to the text thus extending equally into both margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[b!]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.0pt}
    \centering      

    X\hrulefill X
    \vspace{1ex}

    \makebox[\textwidth]{
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrr|rrrr|rrrr}
            & \multicolumn{3}{c}{temp123445} &        \multicolumn{4}{c}{abcdefrw} &               \multicolumn{4}{c}{bnopfsdtagfweau} \\
            $\alpha$ & \# ter & \% gap &         refw & \# ter & \% gap &    rewf & \# path & \# ter & \% gap &  esd  & \# gred \\
            \hline     
            1.60 &     56 &   2.93 &      1191.34 &     34 &   0.05 &  546.43 &    1300 &     31 &   0.38 & 401.20 &   1116 \\
            2.43 &      3 &   8.45 &      1680.47 &     21 &   1.45 &  410.74 &    6428 &     16 &   2.65 & 816.47 &   5896 \\
            2.75 &      9 &   3.97 &       903.57 &     19 &   1.71 &  480.65 & 169,286 &     56 &   2.15 & 539.52 & 11,209 \\
            2.30 &     54 &   2.40 &       798.33 &     56 &   1.97 &  449.87 & 855,441 &     21 &   1.55 & 830.85 & 10,110 \\
            2.50 &     22 &   0.91 &       654.06 &      9 &     -- &  957.18 &      -- &     26 &   0.80 & 475.83 &   7743 \\
            3.75 &     23 &   0.70 &       554.46 &      5 &     -- &  998.54 &      -- &     27 &   0.68 & 577.48 &   7479 \\
            6.00 &     43 &   0.61 &       470.26 &      3 &     -- & 1627.80 &      -- &     28 &   0.58 & 628.28 &   7048 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        }

    \vspace{1ex}
    X\hrulefill X

    \caption{Results on bad data.}\label{tab:results-bad}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The table is now centered with respect of the center of the text (not the center of the page).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the table to extend over the margins and not use `tabularx`, you could use a `resizebox` like e.g. `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{<your entire tabular>}` so that the table itself will be resized to fit into the margins. Of course this will result in a different font size. (This requires `tikz`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[b!]
    \centering      
    \tabcolsep=3.0pt
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{r|rrr|rrrr|rrrr}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{temp123445} &        \multicolumn{4}{c}{abcdefrw} &               \multicolumn{4}{c}{bnopfsdtagfweau} \\
        $\alpha$ & \# ter & \% gap &         refw & \# ter & \% gap &    rewf & \# path & \# ter & \% gap &  esd  & \# gred \\
        \hline     
        1.60 &     56 &   2.93 &      1191.34 &     34 &   0.05 &  546.43 &    1300 &     31 &   0.38 & 401.20 &   1116 \\
        2.43 &      3 &   8.45 &      1680.47 &     21 &   1.45 &  410.74 &    6428 &     16 &   2.65 & 816.47 &   5896 \\
        2.75 &      9 &   3.97 &       903.57 &     19 &   1.71 &  480.65 & 169,286 &     56 &   2.15 & 539.52 & 11,209 \\
        2.30 &     54 &   2.40 &       798.33 &     56 &   1.97 &  449.87 & 855,441 &     21 &   1.55 & 830.85 & 10,110 \\
        2.50 &     22 &   0.91 &       654.06 &      9 &     -- &  957.18 &      -- &     26 &   0.80 & 475.83 &   7743 \\
        3.75 &     23 &   0.70 &       554.46 &      5 &     -- &  998.54 &      -- &     27 &   0.68 & 577.48 &   7479 \\
        6.00 &     43 &   0.61 &       470.26 &      3 &     -- & 1627.80 &      -- &     28 &   0.58 & 628.28 &   7048 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Results on bad data.}\label{tab:results-bad}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]